# How to make a correct Drag and Drop over a tabitem's header?

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, tabitem, ismouseover

My application has a main window with 4 tabitems and each of them has child windows inside of. I want to drag one of them and drop it over a tabitem's header (anyone) to change it's location.

I tried using triggers with the property IsMouseOver but the focus continues on the child window because I had done click on the window to drag it. I read about DragDrop.DoDragDrop but I don't know if is that I looking for. Help !

Comment: Did you [enable AllowDrop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.allowdrop?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) on your tab?

Comment: Yes, and I added a method to Drop too

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/drag-and-drop?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8